# Render recursively a nested data in React , I would like to recover the "name" of this file json

Tags: json, reactjs

how would i make a list of "name" from this list json in

I tried this code but I only get the first "name" json file

```
[
    {
        "id": "LIB1",
        "name": "Library 1",
        "context": "C1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "SKI1",
                "name": "SKill 1",
                "context": "C1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "SKI11",
                        "name": "SKill 11",
                        "context": "C1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI12",
                        "name": "SKill 12",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI13",
                        "name": "SKill 13",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "SKI131",
                                "name": "SKill 131",
                                "context": "C1",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "SKI1311",
                                        "name": "SKill 1311",
                                        "context": "C1",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "SKI13111",
                                                "name": "SKill 13111",
                                                "context": "C1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "SKI2",
                "name": "SKill 2",
                "context": "C1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "SKI21",
                        "name": "SKill 21",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": [
                            null
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI22",
                        "name": "SKill 22",
                        "context": "C1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried this code but I only get the first "name"

```
const PostData =({data})=>{
   return(
       <div>
           <ul>
               {data.map(item => {
                   return <div>
                   <li>
                   {item.name}
                   {item.children.name && <PostData data={item.children.name}/>}
                   </li>

                   </div>

               })}

           </ul>
       </div>
   )
}

const DATA = require('./data.json')


function App() {
 return (
   <div className="App">
       <PostData data={DATA}/>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

I would like to recover the "name" of this file json thanks
Please help me

I tried this code but I only get the first "name"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`item.children.name` doesn't exist, children is an array. You could use `item.children.ength`

If you want to exclude nodes withouta name, you can filter the array first.

Comment: thank you for your help but I still get only the first name

Comment: @pleonasme does not work doesn't help anything in trying to figure out what the problem is, post what you tried in your question

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below plain JS code, considering what you are expecting, you can put this code before return and use names array

Input:

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": "LIB1",
        "name": "Library 1",
        "context": "C1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "SKI1",
                "name": "SKill 1",
                "context": "C1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "SKI11",
                        "name": "SKill 11",
                        "context": "C1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI12",
                        "name": "SKill 12",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI13",
                        "name": "SKill 13",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": "SKI131",
                                "name": "SKill 131",
                                "context": "C1",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "SKI1311",
                                        "name": "SKill 1311",
                                        "context": "C1",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "SKI13111",
                                                "name": "SKill 13111",
                                                "context": "C1"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "SKI2",
                "name": "SKill 2",
                "context": "C1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "SKI21",
                        "name": "SKill 21",
                        "context": "C1",
                        "children": [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "SKI22",
                        "name": "SKill 22",
                        "context": "C1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Below method can be used to fetch names:

```
var names = [];
var getNames = (a) => {
    a.map(item => {
        names.push(item.name);
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("children") && item.children.length) {
            getNames(item.children)
        }
    });
    return names;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to get a flat list, they are using a nested list in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lodash` `_.uniq(_.map(data, 'usernames'))` method to extract the property under that object
something like this.

```
const PostData =({data})=>{
   return(
       <div>
           <ul>
               {data.map(item => {
                   return <div>
                   <li>
                   {item.name}
                   {item.children.name && <PostData data={item.children.name}/>}
                   </li>

                   </div>

               })}

           </ul>
       </div>
   )
}
```

```
const name = _.uniq(_.map(data, 'usernames'))
```